# Backward compatibility of UIWindow rootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, backwards-compatibility, uiwindow

When creating a new Xcode 4 view based project, it creates that line on the applicationDelegate didFinishLaunching method :

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

But the attribute `rootViewController` only appears with iOS 4.0.

What may I write here to be compatible with iOS prior to 4.0?

P.S. : Because of some problems, I won't be able to test the solution, so please it should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use introspection to detect if `UIWindow` class has that property at runtime and if it doesn't, just add view controller's view as subview to the window.

```
if ([UIWindow instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(rootViewController)]) {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
} else {
    [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
}
```

Comment: 100% sure. You can try to create a project in Xcode 3 if you still have a copy of it and see that root view controller's view was being added as subview to the window before they introduced rootViewController property. And `+instancesRespondToSelector:` is one of basic introspection methods used for backwards compatibility.

Comment: What is the difference using #if __IPHONE_MAX_VERSION_ALLOWED >= 40000 and instancesRespondToSelector ?

Comment: `#if` is a compiler conditional statement. When you compile that code with 4.0 or later SDK, it will compile the code between `#if` and `#endif`. `+instancesRespondToSelector:` gets compiled the same way with every sdk and checks this while app is running and then performs the right selector based on that. That's one of the main benefits of Objective-C. A dynamic runtime that lets you do stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

fichek answer is exactly right. +1 on that answer.

However, just keep in mind that iOS 2 apps [are no more accepted in the store](http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/30/iphone-os-2-apps-no-longer-welcome-on-the-app-store/). The same this will *probably* happens with iOS 3 when iOS 5 comes out. And iOS 5 is rumoured to be out in about a month.

Comment: Removing armv6 support and keeping iOS 3.X support would make little sense, so I hope they do remove iOS 3.X support too. Except >3.2 which is very close to iOS 4 api-wise, and even supports this property.

Comment: +1 for dropping iOS 3.x support. It's so ugly to write those backward compatibility codes.